# Copying values from STDIN to a Postgres table is not reflected in WAL

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, wal

I'm using `copy from STDIN` command to insert data into my Postgres table. However, this is not being reflected in the `WriteAheadLogs` (however, using an `INSERT INTO` statement reflects on the `WriteAheadLogs`).

Am I missing something? Should the WAL not reflect changes of `COPY FROM STDIN` command?

All requirements, such as `wal_level` being set to `logical`, and `max_wal_senders` being `>1`, are fulfilled.

Comment: How do you make sure that the `copy` command is not reflected in WAL ? Can you post a reproducible scenario ?

Comment: I have a connector listening to a `logical_replication_slot`. When I use the `INSERT` command, the connector publishes those changes. However, when I use the `COPY FROM STDIN` command, the connector does not publish these changes.

Comment: Which is the  connector name and what is the exact PostgreSQL version ? Could also post the full table DDL ?

Comment: What version?  PostgreSQL does not have a setting with the name `logical_replication`.

Comment: @jjanes my bad. What I meant was `wal_level` is set to `logical`.

Comment: COPY replicates for me, so it must a problem more specific to your setup, rather than a general problem.  Maybe the COPY replication is just being slow?  Does an INSERT done after a COPY (on the same replication slot) replicate?  Anything in the log files?